# Run strace and get output using Java

Tags: java, linux, strace

I need to automatically run strace with Java (On linux system of course).
So when I execute something like:

```
strace -f echo hi
```

I get the output:

```
hi
```

However when I run the command in terminal I get the usual output (Syscalls and everything).
I had this solution in which I am using the "-o" flag to redirect strace output to a file, and then reading the file to get the output, but that's no good for me anymore.
So I don't understand, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code for executing the command:

```
System.out.println(exec("strace -f -q echo hi"));

private String exec(String cmd) {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Sorry if I have a typo somewhere, I was copying this by hand.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem, no output?

Comment: I get the output of 'echo hi'. Not the output of strace. Like I am not using strace at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that strace writes it's output to STDERR.

So the solution is:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```